# Find similar from text entered/selected

Tags: php, mysql

I have a user who has an item in their basket which is, for example: Gears Of War 2 Limited Edition - I want to be able to also show other items but not similar, more like different versions e.g. gears of war 2 game of the year edition

So what I basically want to do, if poossible, is run a search with one less word if nothing comes up, then do it again until I get the desired number of results, or end up with no words.

So, if a user has simply "gears of war" then thats easy as there are many matches eg gears of war 2, gears of war 3 etc its when its a big unique title.

Is that doable? Is that the best way to do it?

Comment: Any chance you can keep a "series" table, and have any game in that series relate to it through a 'series_id' field?

Comment: @Dave No unfortunately, and the data changes daily as its pulled in from various sources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this with only 1 MySQL call. Then create a stored procedure with a simple loop.

throw this into a loop and lop of a word at each iteration

```
var_similar_title = 'Gears of War 2 Limited Edition'
....

SELECT
   product_name
FROM
   product
WHERE
   product_name LIKE CONCAT(var_similar_title,'%')

....
```

A simple way to lop of a word is by using a combination of the REVERSE(), LOCATE() AND SUBSTRING() functions.

or

Something like:

```
SET numWords = (length('gears of war')-length(REPLACE('gears of war', ' ', '')))/length(' ')
```

to get a count of the words in your string (or you can pass this from your php program if you prefer) and then use

```
 SUBSTRING_INDEX('gears_of_war', i)
```

where i is numWords initially and then decrement by 1 each pass through the loop.

EDIT: I'll add this in case you needed a more detailed example:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS findSimilarTitles$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `findSimilarTitles`( title VARCHAR(255), minMatches INT)
BEGIN

DECLARE i INT;
DECLARE var_similar_title VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE var_number_of_matches INT;
SET i = 1;
SET i = (length(title)-length(REPLACE(title, ' ', '')))/length(' ');

WHILE i > 0 DO
   SET title = SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', i);
   SET var_number_of_matches = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE CONCAT(title,'%'));
   IF var_number_of_matches >= minMatches THEN
      SET i = -99;
   ELSE
     SET i = i - 1;
   END IF;
END WHILE;

IF i = -99 THEN
  SELECT product_name FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE CONCAT(title,'%');
ELSE
  SELECT 'No Matching Products';
END IF;

END$$
```

Comment: Thanks, but it won't always be gears of war, it could be "fifa 2011 rooney with hair edition" or something like that

Comment: obviously, you would pass the name of the item as a parameter. LOL. I was just demonstrating how to do it, you'll need to replace those strings with variables in your stored procedure.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I added a more detailed example which you should be able to work with. To execute a stored procedure it would be something like this `CALL findSimilarTitles( <title>, <minimum_number_of_matches>)`

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this would be to start by selecting the products with names that use the same words as the current products and ordering them by the number of words matched

I made a test and used a table using this structure/content: http://i.imgur.com/bwnNd.png

Supposing that the current product is the one with the id 1 and the title "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" I split the title into words, select the products that have at least one of the words in the title, order the list by the number of words matched and get only the first few (4 in the example)

After this, to be sure that you get better results, not just the ones that match the maximum number of words you can use a string comparison algorithm like the levenshtein distance. I used this algorithm as there is a function for this in the php core http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Basically this function tells you the number of transformations you need to apply on a string to get to the other (by transformation it is understood: removing a character, adding one, or changing the value of one)

So by getting the levenshtein distance between the initial title and the one for each result you will know the ones that are closer

When doing this you can find the minumum value (the best as it tells you that the minumum number of transformations are needed) and display the products for which you found this distance

I added a sample script that does this here: http://codepad.org/FKDgo7ph

As a disclaimer: you need to take care of the security of this script, this is just a sample and also integrate it in your system (here product_id and product_name for the current product are static vars)

Also: you can get better results by adding some improvements like:

- implement a list of stop words to remove from the initial title (to be sure you don't get "points" for words like "and", "or" etc
- reverse the words before getting the score and assign a growing performance for each word matched, this way being sure that words at the start of the title are more important than the ones at the end

Comment: thank you, thats been really helpful to me on a learning curve, massively appreciated.